# WPF ComboBox does not show current item when it is a DependencyObject

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have this very simple Combobox in my XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb1" Width="200" Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

and this is my code behind:

```
public class Test //: System.Windows.DependencyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var col = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
    cmb1.DataContext = col;
    col.Add(new Test { Name = "A" });
    col.Add(new Test { Name = "B" });
    col.Add(new Test { Name = "C" });
    col.Add(new Test { Name = "D" });
}
```

As long as **Test** class is NOT inherited from **DependencyObject** everything is fine. But when it is inherited, ComboBox does not show *current item* when it is not expanded. 
Current Item is selected when I click on ComboBox and see its drop-box.
[image]

Comment: I have found if I add DisplayMemberPath="Name" to ComboBox, it would work fine. Now, the question is why DependencyObject (or ComboBox) does not use ToString() method and expects display member path?

Comment: Change Test to Label (or some other 'DependancyObject' of choice) it works fine. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the answer by [karmicpuppet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409741/karmicpuppet) in a now deleted question:

> This is interesting. Well, I've looked
>   at the ComboBox class using Reflector
>   and I see that in the
>   ComboBox.UpdateSelectionBoxItems()
>   method, part of it does something
>   like:
>
> If ItemTemplate, ItemTemplateSelector,
>   and ItemStringFormat were not set, and
>   selected item is a DependencyObject
>   that is not derived from UIElement,
>   call the ExtractString(selectedItem)
>   method.
>
> The ComboBox.ExtractString(dObj)
>   method, on the other hand, apparently
>   checks to see if the selectedItem
>   (which is a DependencyObject) is
>   either a TextBlock, a Visual, or a
>   TextElement to display the appropriate
>   string. Otherwise, it will return
>   string.Empty.

So the easiest solution would be to set this on the Combobox:

```
ItemStringFormat="{}{0}"
```

Comment: That is a relief to hear ComboBox deals with DependencyObject and other classes separately. Now it makes more sense that why it does not call ToString() method of the Test class when it is a DependencyObject. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Related: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787577/why-is-selector-issyncronizedwithcurrentitem-only-necessary-when-items-are-depend/3788108#37881081.) I have on another question. Based on that, I think it maybe a bug.  And if you do at least one of the following, the selection should work:

1. Specify an ItemTemplate.
2. Specify an ItemTemplateSelector.
3. Specify an ItemStringFormat.
4. Derive the item from UIElement.

**EDIT:**  Question got deleted.  Just see my explanation on the other answer for this question.

Comment: Oh crap, the question got deleted.  But yeah, just see what bitboink posted.  That should explain it.  =)